# How can I use Rails routes to redirect from one domain to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

My app used to run on foo.tld but now it runs on bar.tld. Requests will still come in for foo.tld, I want to redirect them to bar.tld.

How can I do this in rails routes?

Comment: Have you considered DNS forwarding?

Comment: you can do it in application_controller: 
if request.host == 'some.site'
      redirect_to url_for(host: 'site', subdomain: 'another'), status: :moved_permanently
    end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit more modern approach:

```
constraints(host: 'www.mydomain.com') do
  get '/:param' => redirect('https://www.mynewurl.com/:param')
end
```

Comment: Good answer, but (in Rails 5, at least) the param needs to be included in `%{}`. This would give you: `get '/:param', to: redirect('https://www.mynewurl.com/%{param}')`

Answer (score 44):

This works in Rails 3.2.3

```
constraints(:host => /foo.tld/) do
  match "/(*path)" => redirect {|params, req| "http://bar.tld/#{params[:path]}"}
end
```

This works in Rails 4.0

```
constraints(:host => /foo.tld/) do
  match "/(*path)" => redirect {|params, req| "http://bar.tld/#{params[:path]}"},  via: [:get, :post]
end
```

Comment: For me this worked everywhere except the home page. The solution is good enough for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: The splat rout by itself matches a nonempty string, so root URL won't be matched. Just add the parentheses: `match "/(*path)"...`

Comment: Rails 4: add `via: [:get, :post]` to the `match` options

Comment: Use // instead of http:// to ensure the redirect is protocol independent and works for http as well as for https.

Comment: Curious as to why not use:    "via: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete]"

Comment: @justingordon [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372896/rails-ensuring-www-is-in-the-url#comment4763365_4373733) on a similar question suggests that `GET` and `HEAD` requests should redirect (301 response) while any other methods (`PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`, and `POST`) should technically be blocked (400 or 404 response). I tend to agree with this view since these methods should only be called from within the correct (redirected) site while `GET` requests will most likely come from old links etc.

Comment: @VanderHoorn I have a redirection loop with => redirect {|params, req| "http://bar.tld/#{params[:path]}"} and a non secure alert with => redirect {|params, req| "//bar.tld/#{params[:path]}"}, what should i do ?

Comment: I think you want to escape the dot in the domain, i.e. `/foo\.tld/`. Also might want to match end of string, i.e. `/foo\.tld$/` so as not to redirect requests to http://foo.tld.bar.tld/path.

Comment: You usually don't want to redirect via POST. It's a little misleading.

Answer (score 6):

This does the job of the other answer. Though in addition, it **preserves query strings as well**. (Rails 4):

```rb
# http://foo.tld?x=y redirects to http://bar.tld?x=y
constraints(:host => /foo.tld/) do
  match '/(*path)' => redirect { |params, req|
    query_params = req.params.except(:path)
    "http://bar.tld/#{params[:path]}#{query_params.keys.any? ? "?" + query_params.to_query : ""}"
  }, via: [:get, :post]
end
```

Note: If you're dealing with full domains instead of just subdomains, use `:domain` instead of `:host`.

Comment: Actually `"http://bar.tld#{req.fullpath}"` because `req.fullpath` already contains the leading forward slash.

Answer (score 6):

similar to other answers, this one worked for me:

```
# config/routes.rb
constraints(host: "foo.com", format: "html") do
  get ":any", to: redirect(host: "bar.com", path: "/%{any}"), any: /.*/
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The following solution redirects multiple domains on `GET` and `HEAD` requests while returning http 400 on all other requests (as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372896/rails-ensuring-www-is-in-the-url#comment4763365_4373733) in a similar question).

**/lib/constraints/domain_redirect_constraint.rb:**

```
module Constraints
  class DomainRedirectConstraint
    def matches?(request)
      request_host = request.host.downcase
      return request_host == "foo.tld1" || \
             request_host == "foo.tld2" || \
             request_host == "foo.tld3"
    end
  end
end
```

**/config/routes.rb:**

```
require 'constraints/domain_redirect_constraint'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match "/(*path)", to: redirect {|p, req| "//bar.tld#{req.fullpath}"}, via: [:get, :head], constraints: Constraints::DomainRedirectConstraint.new
  match "/(*path)", to: proc { [400, {}, ['']] }, via: :all, constraints: Constraints::DomainRedirectConstraint.new

  ...
end
```

For some reason `constraints Constraints::DomainRedirectConstraint.new do` didn't work for me on heroku but `constraints: Constraints::DomainRedirectConstraint.new` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
constraints(host: /subdomain\.domain\.com/) do
  match '/(*path)' => redirect { |params, req|
    "https://www.example.com#{req.fullpath}"
  }, via: [:get, :head]
end
```

I use this when using custom domains on Heroku and I want to redirect from the myapp.herokuapp.com -> www.example.com.