# How to get https://www.example.com to redirect to https://example.com without a htaccess file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, redirect, google-cloud-platform

I'm using google cloud platform to host my site and namecheap for the domain name. I want any traffic that hits https://www.example.com to redirect to https://example.com.

I currently have http://www.example.com and http://example.com redirecting to https://example.com from using DNS URL redirects and having `secure: always` as a handler in my app.yaml file (for ruby on rails).

I dont know how to have https://www.example.com redirect to https://example.com. I've tried adding a `.htaccess` file but couldn't get it to work so maybe there is a configuration I can have in the app.yaml file or some other way for this to work.

Comment: @DanCornilescu that link is for python and isnt quite the same problem unfortunately

Comment: Can you link to what Google Cloud Publisher is? A [quick web search](https://www.google.com/?q=google%20cloud%20publisher) only shows links to [Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://www.google.com/?q=google%20cloud%20publisher), which is presumably not the product you're talking about.

Comment: @E.Anderson Sorry it was a typo for 'platform' (yea it was pretty late when I wrote this up)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using App Engine in particular.

I don't think that app.yaml supports matching on the hostname; you can either [implement the redirect in your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918529/how-can-i-use-rails-routes-to-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another) or add a second service to your app which only serves the redirects and use [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_with_a_dispatch_file) to route requests to non-canonical domain to the redirect service.

Sample [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dispatchref) if you decide to use two services:

```
dispatch:
  # Official site is at example.com
  - url: "example.com/*"
    module: default

  # Default module serves simple redirect.
  - url: "*/*"
    module: redirect
```

Comment: It doesnt look like these solutions work for https redirecting. I have http redirecting working from the app.yaml file.