# How to forward request to another subdomain in routes rails based on path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What I want to do is,

When someone make request to http://www.domain.com/api, the server forward this request to http://main.domain.com/api

Now I configure my rails routes on www.domain.com like this:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users
  end

 namespace :v2 do
   resources :sessions
 end
 match 'v:api/*path', :to => redirect("http://main.domain.com/api/%{path}")
end
```

currently The http request is not accepted on main.domain.com

Any suggestion ?

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918529/how-can-i-use-rails-routes-to-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another

Comment: i suggest rack redirect https://medium.com/@paulskarseth/rails-4-rack-middleware-redirect-5f48d4dd76d0#.t65hpoayh

Answer (score 0):

In your ApplicationController

```
 def redirect_api
     if request.host == 'http://www.domain.com/api'
         redirect_to 'http://main.domain.com/api'
     end
 end
```