# How to initialize a Websocket on existing port in Puma server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ruby application in which I am using puma web server which listens on port 8008.

Now I have got requirement to implement socket.io/websockets.

I was exploring the possibility of using EventMachine::WebSocket but since my puma application is already using port 8008, I cannot bind to 8008.

My UI is written in javascript and puma application basically exposes rest endpoints.

How can I implement websockets in such a scenario?

Comment: just use a different port, only one application can use a port at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave the Rails server on the port it's running on, and redirect your websocket requests to the other server which runs on a different port.

[This question/answer essentially describes the implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918529/how-can-i-use-rails-routes-to-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another)
So you'd probably want something like:

`match "/websocket/(*path)" => redirect {|params, req| "http://your.domain:8009/#{params[:path]}"}`

where 8009 is the port your Websocket server runs on.